# Compare element value with current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a JavaScript function trying to get the value from `span` and compare that value with today's `date`

The logic is :

If span date is more than 30 days, change it's background color to **green**

If span date is more than 60 days, change it's background color to **blue**

If span date is more than 90 days, change it's background color to **red**

My span currently is :

```
<span class="awsome">02/04/2011</span>
var s =`$('.awsome span').text();`    
alert(s);
```

I want to compare it with :

```
var d = new Date();
var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate();
```

My question is how do I compare and change the color at the same time ?

Comment: Your span has the year last, but `stdDate` has the year first.

Comment: You also need to add leading zeroes if the day or month is 1 digit.

Comment: It's not a great idea to use es6 constructs like backticks, even though the look cool.

Comment: Only a question like this could get 5 responses in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function parseDate(str) {
        var mdy = str.split('/')
        return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
    }

    function daydiff(first, second) {
        return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24);
    }

    var today = new Date();
    console.log(today);
    $('.awesome').each(function() {
  var newDate = parseDate($(this).html());
        console.log(newDate);
        var difference = Math.abs(daydiff(newDate, today));
        if (difference > 90) {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else if (difference > 60) {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
        }
        else if (difference > 30) {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="awesome">02/04/2011</span>
<span class="awesome">02/04/2016</span>
<span class="awesome">02/04/2015</span>
<span class="awesome">09/04/2015</span>
<span class="awesome">10/04/2015</span>
<span class="awesome">11/04/2015</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use jquery, you can do that to change the background color of your span:

```
$( ".awsome span" ).each(function() {
  var date = $(this).text();
  // Here you would do your date comparison, setting isToday to true if the date is equal to today
  if (isToday)
       $( this ).css( "background-color", "green" );
  else
       $( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date(s)` to get a Date object from your `<span>` date (equivalent to February 4, 2011). With your `var d = new Date()`, you get the current date/time. With these two, you can use `d - s` to find how many milliseconds after the date in the span that the current date is. Since it is in milliseconds, you would then want to divide by `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` and round down to get the number of complete days. Let's say we stored the difference in `var difference`. 1000 to convert it to seconds, 60 to convert to minutes, another 60 to convert to hours and finally 24 to convert to days. Since you only want complete days, you round down as anything more is irrelevant.

Once you've found the difference in days, you use jQuery's `.css()` function to change the colour by using

`.css("background-color", difference > 90 ? "red" : difference > 60 ? "blue" : difference > 30 ? "green" : "white")`

The `?` is a ternary operator. First, it checks if `difference > 90` and if so, returns "red", otherwise it returns what's after the `:`. In this case, we have another ternary operator after that so it keeps going until it finds something that is true, otherwise it returns `"white"` since that is what is returned if the last statement evaluates to false. The last colour would be whatever default colour is.

Since you have a lot of `<span class="awesome">`s, you'd need to iterate through them and do it for each one using `.each()`. So your complete code would look something like:

```
$(".awesome").each(function() {
    var s = new Date($(this).text()),
        d = new Date(),
        difference = <ath.round((d - s) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $(this).css("background-color", difference > 90 ? "red" : difference > 60 ? "blue" : difference > 30 ? "green" : "white")
});
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epmvLZ for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over all the spans and then change the color. you can use jQuery [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) Something like this should work :

```
 $('.awsome span').each(function() {
   //compare the dates and change color 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

VanillaJS:

```js
var day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.awsome");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function(span) {
  var date = new Date(Date.parse(span.innerText));
  var days = (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime()) / day;

  if (days > 30) {
    span.style.backgroundColor = "#aaffaa";
  }
  if (days > 60) {
    span.style.backgroundColor = "#aaaaff";
  }
  if (days > 90) {
    span.style.backgroundColor = "#ffaaaa";
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="awsome">02/04/2015</span>
<span class="awsome">07/03/2015</span>
<span class="awsome">07/25/2015</span>
```

Or if you want to stick with jQuery:

```js
var day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
$("span.awsome").each(function() {
  var date = new Date(Date.parse(this.innerText));
  var days = (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime()) / day;

  if (days > 30) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#aaffaa");
  }
  if (days > 60) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#aaaaff");
  }
  if (days > 90) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ffaaaa");
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="awsome">02/04/2015</span>
<span class="awsome">07/03/2015</span>
<span class="awsome">07/25/2015</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to suggest using `addClass()` rather than `css()`; it's generally considered 'cleaner' to update a class-name rather than directly manipulate the CSS of the given node, since using class-names, adding or removing, means you don't have to keep track of individual properties that were changed or updated, and allows for easy re-styling during (inevitable) updates to the design.

That said, I'd suggest:

```
// today's date:
var today = new Date(),
// 'empty' variables for use in
// the later loop:
    delta, spanDate;

// selecting the <span> elements with the class-name of
// 'awsome' (note that I've preserved the misspelling),
// and then using the addClass() method:
$('span.awsome').addClass(function (index, currentClasses) {
    // jQuery methods tend to 'internally' iterate over
    // the collections to which they're chained, inside
    // the anonymous function 'this' refers to the current
    // DOM-node held inside the jQuery object/collection
    // over which we're iterating.

    // here we find the date represented by the text within the
    // <span> element's; we retrieve the text with the
    // Node.textContent property, split that string on the '/'
    // characters to form an array, we reverse that array and
    // join the string back together using the '/' character,
    // in order to convert dd/mm/yyyy into yyyy/mm/dd:
    spanDate = new Date(this.textContent.split('/').reverse().join('/'));

    // subtracting the date held in the <span> from today's date,
    // dividing the results by '(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)' (which gives
    // the number of milliseconds per day) to find out how many
    // days the two dates are apart:
    delta = (today - spanDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    // if the difference is less than 31 days (because you
    // specified 'more than 30' in your description) we
    // return the class-name of 'white':
    if (delta < 31) {
        return 'white';

    // otherwise, if it's more than 30, and less than
    // 61 we return the class-name 'green':
    } else if (delta > 30 && delta < 61) {
        return 'green';

    // and so on:
    } else if (delta > 60 && delta < 91) {
        return 'blue';
    } else if (delta > 90) {
        return 'red';
    }
});
```

```js
var today = new Date(),
  delta, spanDate;

$('span.awsome').addClass(function(index, spanNode) {
  spanDate = new Date(this.textContent.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  delta = (today - spanDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

  if (delta < 31) {
    return 'white';
  } else if (delta > 30 && delta < 61) {
    return 'green';
  } else if (delta > 60 && delta < 91) {
    return 'blue';
  } else if (delta > 90) {
    return 'red';
  }
});
```

```css
.white {
  background-color: white;
}
.green {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.blue {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="awsome">03/09/2015</span>

<span class="awsome">03/08/2015</span>

<span class="awsome">03/07/2015</span>

<span class="awsome">03/06/2015</span>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/48xor7jz/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).